# Forwarding JWT tokens with docker swarm?

Tags: security, docker, jwt, docker-swarm

When docker swarm is load balancing does it also have a built in way to forward a JWT token to the server handling the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JWT token is normally included as a part of the Layer 7 HTTP headers, which will be forwarded onto the container.

The only information you will lose is the [originating IP of the request](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25526).